Why isn't my PyTorch imported correctly on VS code?
I downloaded PyTorch for the first time to use for a research project in school. I used the command "pip3 install torch" to download it on my terminal and everything went smoothly at first, but if I try to import it into files on VS code and run them, it reads, "ImportError: No module named torch." However, the code runs smoothly if I run it on the terminal. I've tried downloading it again through the venv, but it still doesn't work.
From here, I'm not sure how to go about and fix this? Should I just try uninstalling and reinstalling? If anyone could give specific instructions and advice on how to resolve this, that would be greatly appreciated.
For reference, my current version of Python is 3.12.5 and PyTorch 2.4.1.
edit: through trying import sys; print(sys.path), I found that my VS code seems to be using Python 2.7 instead of 3.12. Afterwards, I tried to switch the interpreter path to 3.12.5 ('venv': venv) as the recommended setting, but the program on VS code remains as 2.7. How to resolve?
VS code output:
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']

terminal output: ['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/Users/-/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages']

EDIT: Following suggestions to create a new venv, the python file still seems to be using python 2.7 anyway. I've tried making a brand new folder and setting up venv for 3.12, but the new python file still is 2.7. Is there another way to resolve this?

It sounds like your VS Code is configured to use a different installation of python on your computer.

Run this short program in the terminal and in VS Code, and edit the question to show the outputs import sys; print(sys.path)

What do you mean "import it into files on VS code and run them"? Do you mean you open the file in VS code and run with VS code debugger by pressing F5? If so, make sure to configure the debugger to run with your venv.

vscode seems to use old venvs in your project.Remove your .venv folder from your project and create a new one and install necessary packages.

@AmadeuszLiu The python file still seems to be using python 2.7 anyway. I've tried making a brand new folder and setting up venv for 3.12, but the new python file still is 2.7. Is there another way to resolve this?

@JohnGordon How do I change which installation of python it uses?

which environment you are using?Conda,venv or other?

@AmadeuszLiu I'm using venv. When I go to "Python: Select Interpreter" in VS code, it says it's Python 3.12.5.

That's weird,would you mind try reinstalling the extension, and in settings.json change
 "python.defaultInterpreterPath" to the path of your python3 installation? Then try reopen the project and see if the issue still exist.

My apologies , but what extension do you mean I should reinstall? Additionally, is the path the output I received from the terminal (shown in original post)?

Python extension pack.And set the Python path to the 3.12 one installed on your machine.

In VSCode you can open the Command Palette with Ctrl+Shift+P and the search for Python: Select Interpreter. There you can select the Python version you want to use and from then on, the scripts you execute from VSCode will use that version by default.

When I select the Python version I want to use (3.12.5), the output for "import sys; print(sys.path)" is still 2.7.
